# Duda sobre password_verify

Tags: php, mysqli

Intento hacer al login con el `password_verify`, pero el error `Undefined Index: contrasena` no deja de aparecer. Este es el código. Por cierto, sí registro al usuario con la contraseña encriptada (`password_hash`).

```
    if(isset($_POST['login_btn']))
    {   //Valida valores del formulario
        //$errores = validarUsuario($_POST, ['login_btn']);
        $correo     = $_POST['correo'];
        $contrasena = $_POST['password'];


            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios1 WHERE nombre=? OR correo=? LIMIT 1";
            $usuario = getRegistroSimple($sql, 'ss', [$correo, $correo]);

            if (!empty($usuario)) //Si se encontró el correo(usuario)
            {   
                if (password_verify($contrasena, $usuario['contrasena'])) //Esta línea es la que mara undefined index
                {
                    loginPorId($usuario['id']);
                }
                else //Si no coincide 
                {
                    $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Correo o contraseña incorrecto";
                }       
            }
            else 
            {//Si el usuario no se encuentra
                $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Usuario o contraseña incorrecto";
            }   
        }
 ?>
```

Aquí la función:

```
function getRegistroSimple($sql, $types, $params)
{
    global $conexion;
    $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $usuario = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $stmt->close();
    return $usuario;

}
```

Comment: Validaste que `$usuario` tiene un valor valido para `password`?

Comment: Dice claramente que en `$usuario` no hay un índice llamado `contrasena`. Depura tu objeto mediante `var_dump($usuario);` así verás cómo está constituido y cómo tienes que usarlo.

Comment: `["contrasena"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$cCSDRH0vDDNWCy0Y1BElTOtiSon6YTG2hybFOTGV0HGp7Kht09OBq"`  Me muestra todos los valores de la consulta, y el campo que quiero verificar, al parecer debería estar correcto, ¿no?

Comment: Pon la funcion `getRegistroSimple`para que podamos ver como se recupera.

Comment: Tengo la impresión de que en `$usuario` es un array de array y en el ultimo nivel estan los datos que bucas. Algo asi como [0] => Array ([contrasena] => "...." ). Pon el `var_dump` completo.

Comment: Este es el `var_dump` completo: `array(1) 
{  [0]=> array(9) 
{  ["id"]=> int(92) 
 ["rol_id"]=> int(1) 
 ["nombre"]=> string(15) "Eduardo Enrique" 
 ["ap_p"]=> string(6) "Molina" 
 ["ap_m"]=> string(7) "Esparza" 
 ["dep_id"]=> int(1) 
 ["fecha"]=> string(19) "2019-04-15 15:43:40" 
 ["correo"]=> string(30) "eduardo.molina.isc@outlook.com" 
 ["contrasena"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$cCSDRH0vDDNWCy0Y1BElTOtiSon6YTG2hybFOTGV0HGp7Kht09OBq" 
} } `

Comment: Es lo que te decia, al hacer un fetch_all, obtienes un array de resultados. Usa fetch_array para obtener solo un registro. https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Vale, gracias..

Comment: Puedes poner también esto en el método: `return $usuario[0];` y te estará devolviendo el array de usuarios ya sacado de la clave `0` y el resto del código funcionará como lo tienes. Dado que es un método para obtener un solo registro (eso se intuye por el nombre que le has dado -`getRegistroSimple()`-), no hay ningún problema en hacerlo así.

Comment: @JDev pon eso como respuesta

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro hecho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que al hacer un `fetch_all` obtienes un array de registros.

Para obtener un unico resultado usa `fetch_array`

En tu caso:

```
$usuario = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```